# Есть ли в JavaScript аналог export() из php?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть ли в js (или можно ли реализовать) функцию - аналог export() в php?
Т.е. у меня есть массив

```
var arr = ["variable1","variable3","variable2"];
```

Я делаю в коде чтото вроде export(arr); и уже ниже мне будут доступны переменные с именами: variable1, variable2, variable3. 
Важно, все они не должны быть объявлены глобально а как обычно, если export() сделали внутри ф-и значит они и будут жить внутри этой ф-и, т.е. export() просто сделает в данном случае:

```
var variable1;
var variable2;
var variable3;
```

А если внутри каждой variable что-то есть то export() присвоит ей это значение а не просто объявит ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    a: 100,
    b: 200
};

for(var k in obj) {
    this[k] = obj[k];
}
console.log(a); // 100
console.log(b); // 200
```

Comment: Это код будет рабоать только в глобалном контексте.

Comment: @dzhioev как сделать чтобы в локальном работал?

Comment: @sanu0074, без eval боюсь никак.

Comment: @sanu0074 лучше объясните, зачем вам это нужно. Поверьте, вы хотите странного.